# Any batch file to shorten dbf file

Tags: batch-file

Can we have any batch file to shorten dbf file?

For exammple Filename:BILLING_CODING_BW1 Output : BILL_BW1

IT PICKS OUT  first four characters from starting and then picks from _(underscore) till the end.

Comment: Can you have shown some effort yo solve the problem? Do you want me to write for you? If you answered yes, than this question is off topic for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I am not into much familiar with dos commands and batch files just know a bit. Can you Please help me in overcoming with this situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: DOS is Disk Operating System from the 1980/1990s, are you still using it? Or do you mean **WINDOWS** batch file?

Comment: WINDOWS BATCH FILE.

Comment: I thought you were talking about MS-DOS since you said DOS.

Comment: OK,can I have a solution for it?.I do this manually on a daily basis and it takes  lot of time

Comment: No. Unless you shown your effort on solving the issue. Please read www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I Can do that Using SSIS(BI tool) but I want using batch file and I don't know even the basic of writing codes for batch file.

Comment: Go https://www.ss64.com - A very good site to start learning batch, and other languages.

Comment: Thanks for your help.